# pyspark and jupyter notebook doesn't work windows 10

Tags: pyspark, windows-10, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I followed this guide step by step to install pyspark and jupyter notebook on my PC windows 10:
http://www.jbencina.com/blog/2017/07/15/installing-pyspark-jupyter-notebook-windows/

I've set everything exactly as the guide says, but when I run the command "pyspark" I receive this error message:

error executing Jupyter command 'notebook': [Errno 'jupyter-notebook' not found] 2

Tried to look for a solution but I didn't find any case specifically like mine, and the most similar were about pyspark on linux.

If anyone could explain me what I need to change in order to make it work, I would be greateful!
If anyone also have some other guide about how to use pyspark on windows, would be great too, I'm still a newbie.

Comment: run a `pip list` command - can you see `jupyter` in the list of installed packages?

Answer (score -1):

INSTALL PYSPARK on Windows 10 
JUPYTER-NOTEBOOK With ANACONDA NAVIGATOR

### STEP 1

**Download Packages**

1) spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz [Download](https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html)

2) java jdk 8 version [Download](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)

3) Anaconda v 5.2 [Download](https://www.anaconda.com/download/)

4) scala-2.12.6.msi [Download](http://scala-2.12.6.msi)

5) hadoop v2.7.1[Download](https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils)

### STEP 2

MAKE SPARK FOLDER IN **C:/** DRIVE AND PUT EVERYTHING INSIDE IT 
[It will look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsTrv.png)

**NOTE : DURING INSTALLATION OF SCALA GIVE PATH OF SCALA  INSIDE SPARK FOLDER**

### STEP 3

NOW SET NEW WINDOWS ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES

1. `HADOOP_HOME=C:\spark\hadoop`
2. `JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151`
3. `SCALA_HOME=C:\spark\scala\bin`
4. `SPARK_HOME=C:\spark\spark\bin`
5. `PYSPARK_PYTHON=C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\python.exe`
6. `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter.exe`
7. `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS=notebook`
8. **NOW SELECT PATH OF SPARK** :

   Click on Edit and add New

   Add "**C:\spark\spark\bin**” to variable “Path” Windows

### STEP 4

- Make folder where you want to store Jupyter-Notebook outputs and files
- After that open Anaconda command prompt and **cd Folder name**
- then enter **Pyspark**

thats it your browser will pop up with Juypter localhost

### STEP 5

Check pyspark is working or not !

Type simple code and run it

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
a = Row(name = 'Vinay' , age=22 , height=165)
print("a: ",a)
```

Comment: I think step 1) can be install by `pip install pyspark`